# Azure Boards process type after migration from TFS 2010 to DevOps Server 2020 on-premises

Tags: tfs, process

We have migrated a TFS 2010 server with a couple of project collections to Azure DevOps 2020 on-premises. All migrated data looks fine, but in the mirgrated projects, it is not possible to create an inherited process (the context menu of a process only provides "New team project" and "Export". Whereas in newly created process collections it is possible (the contex menu provides "New team project", "Create inherited process", and others. Our first idea was, that the migrated collections use the XML process type, but also we found no way to convert this or change to the inherited process type.
Is there a way to use inherited process in our migrated process collections?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to use inherited process in our migrated process collections?

I am afraid that there is no such method to migrate the XML process to inherited process.

If you want to use inherited process, you need to create a new Collection with inherited process in Azure DevOps Server 2022.

This feature exists in Azure Devops Service. You could refer to this doc: [Clone a Hosted XML process to an Inheritance process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/upgrade-hosted-to-inherited?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

According to the doc, this feature only exists in the **Azure Devops Service**. When you select azure devops server 2022 in the drop-down box in the upper left corner, you can directly see that it is not supported.

Here is a [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/614232/bring-inherited-process-to-existing-projects-for-a.html) about this feature. Our product group has decided not to implement this feature on azure devops server.

> For those customers who wish to go to Inherited, you have the
> following choices.
>
> 1. Move to the Azure DevOps Service
> 2. Create a new inherited collection and continue your project work
>    within that collection

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. Unfortunately our security rules to not allow the IT department to use the cloud version.

Comment: Got it. In your situation, I am afraid that there is no such method can meet your requirement.